# Search a value in array of structures C

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I would like to know the fastest search method for array of structures

```
typedef struct fault_table_type {
    fault_types_t                    fault_code;         
    faultmanger_time_            process_time;      
    fault_behavior_enum_type_t       behavior;          
    FAILUREMGR_ACTION               fault_action;      
    bool                              forward_fault;    
    } fault_table_type_t;

static const fault_table_type_t fault_table[] = {
    
     {  COMMS_FAILURE,           60,         BEHAVIOR_3,   FAIL,    false,},  
     {   QUEUE_FAILURE,               10,         BEHAVIOR_1,      RESET,       true},

    };
```

If I am just getting the `fault_code`. How do I search this value in the fault_table. Thanks

Comment: simple linear search, unless its huge or ultra time critical

Answer (score 1):

Linear search via a good old `for`-loop.  The compiler will probably unroll the loop that for you.  If not write a macro to check index i and call it for your 2 records.  You could try `lfind()` but it will probably be a little slower just due to function call overheads.

The next step (if you have 1000+ records) is to sort your key either the array itself array or a separate index then use `bsearch()`.  If you change from an array of struct to a struct of arrays then your key is sorted and serves as an index.

In either case you start with code optimized for readability.  Benchmark it and then see if you need to make changes.  You also want to be more precise what you mean with fastest mean: fewest cpu cycles, fewest cache misses, what access pattern (cold vs hot), user time etc.